# qt addin 1.2.4 not creating new project in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012

I installed the Qt addin 1.2.4 and added msvc2012_opengl for Qt 5.3 in the qt configuration. After this I try to create a new Qt application through the New project wizard, and it doesn't create the project. It loops infinitely on the new project wizard, select application type page, when I click next. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: To understand a reason, you should build Qt Addin by yourself and debug it. Idea, what's going on: your installation (msvs/qt/qt addin) is corrupted.

Comment: How do I reset it? I'm still starting Qt, building and debugging is not what I want to spend my time on.